# setHorizontalBias in ConstraintSet with view created programmatically

Tags: android, imageview, android-constraintlayout

I have this `ConstraintLayout`:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_live_icons_layout"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/fragment_live_clock"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fragment_live_progress_bar_time"
            android:background="@color/futbolinAzul"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_n"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_n"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/height_sm"/>
```

And, programmatically I want to add `ImageViews` inside it, trying to obtain this picture as the result:

[image: result desired]

Where the white rectangle is the `ConstraintLayout` and the ball and the yellow cards are the different `ImageView`s added programmatically.

First of all, I created one `ImageView`:

```
iconImages = v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_live_icons_layout); //CONSTRAINTLAYOUT
ImageView imageView =  new ImageView(getContext());
imageView.setId(View.generateViewId());
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_ball);
```

After that, I add the `imageView` to the `ConstraintLayout`:

```
iconsImages.addView(imageView);
```

Then I created a `ConstraintSet` and i cloned the `ConstraintLayout`:

```
ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
constraintSet.clone(iconImages);
```

And finally I set the `horizontalBias` using my variable `minutes`:

```
constraintSet.connect(imageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, iconsImages.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);
constraintSet.connect(imageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, iconsImages.getId(), ConstraintSet.LEFT, 0);

 //   constraintSet.setVerticalBias(imageView.getId(),  0.5f);
    constraintSet.setHorizontalBias(imageView.getId(),  (float)minutes/90);
    constraintSet.applyTo(iconsImages);
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(iconsImages);
```

Where it usually has values in the `minutes` variable between 15 and 80. The problem is all the `imageView`s are set at the start o the `ConstraintLayout`.

Like this:
[image: error adding imageViews]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right constraint seems to be missing. bias must apply both side constraints.

```
constraintSet.connect(imageView.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, iconsImages.getId(), ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 0);
```